# How to reorder discrete y axis on a plot with facets, flipped coordinates, and continuous x axis

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

**Objective:**
I am trying to draw a plot of data on cities in several countries, grouped by region, then arranged by my own `order` from 1 at the top in ascending order going down the plot along the y axis.

The plot is currently grouping the regions in reverse alphabetical order; I'd like it to be in alphabetical order as well. Also, it is currently arranging the nations alphabetically. My `order` is not being used.

**What I've tried so far:**
You'll see two lines of code that have been commented out below:

```
#aspect.ratio=1/5, #I tried this and it did not work for me
```

and

```
#coord_fixed(ratio=1/500) + #new one for fixing y axis spacing #this did not solve it either
```

and I've tried to solve it using the solution proposed here: https://www.r-bloggers.com/ordering-categories-within-ggplot2-facets-2/ with this code:

```
group_by(rdatacities$region, rdatacities$country) %>%                  
  arrange(desc(contribution)) %>%                
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(country = factor(paste(country, region, sep = "__"), levels = rev(paste(country, region, sep = "__")))) %>% 
  # --ggplot here--
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) gsub("__.+$", "", x))
```

but `group_by(rdatacities$region, rdatacities$country) %>%` throws this error:

> Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
>     no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "character"

**I am not an R expert, I believe this to be a minimal, complete, and verifiable example, but if it's a wall of terrible code, I apologize in advance.**

```
library(readxl)
library(grid)
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
library(graphics)
library(grDevices)
library(datasets)

p<-ggplot(rdatacities, aes(x=country, y=target, size=citiesorig)) +
geom_point(shape=21, alpha=.6, stroke=.75) + #municipal targets
facet_grid(region ~ ., scales = "free_y", space = "free_y") + #regional clusters
geom_point(data=rdatanation, shape=0, size=2.5, stroke=1, aes(colour='red')) 
#national targets

plot <- p + theme(
plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5), legend.key=element_rect(fill='white'), 
panel.background = element_blank(), plot.margin = margin(2), 
axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), panel.grid.major.y= element_line(size=.2, linetype='solid', colour='grey'), 
axis.text.y = element_text(size=6),
panel.grid.major.x= element_blank(),  axis.line.x = element_blank(), 
axis.ticks.x=element_line(color='black'),

#aspect.ratio=1/5, #I tried this and it did not work for me
strip.background=element_rect(fill = NA, size = 0, color = "white", linetype = "blank")
) + 
#coord_fixed(ratio=1/500) + #new one for fixing y axis spacing #this did not solve it either
scale_y_continuous(name="Target by 2030 as Percent of Base Year", labels = percent) +
scale_x_discrete(name="Country", expand=waiver()) +
coord_flip(ylim = c(0, 3)) +
ggtitle("National vs. Municipal GHG Emissions Targets") +
guides(colour = guide_legend(order = 1, "Targets"),
     size = guide_legend(order = 2,"Municipal")) +
scale_color_manual(name="Targets", labels = c("National"), values = c('#843C0C'))

plot
```

Here is a sample of the data from rdatacities:

```
region country target cities order citiesorig
   <chr>  <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 EAP    JPN      0.660      1    71          1
 2 EAP    JPN      0.75       2    71          2
 3 EAP    JPN      0.8        1    71          1
 4 EAP    JPN      0.85       1    71          1
 5 EAP    JPN      0.88       1    71          1
 6 EAP    JPN      0.96       1    71          1
 7 EAP    KOR      0.6        1    72          1
 8 ECA    ALB      0.22       1    68          1
 9 ECA    AZE      0.2        1    65          1
10 ECA    BLR      0.2        2    62          6
# ... with 391 more rows
```

Here is a sample of the data from rdatanations

```
region countryname       country target   EmBase EmCBase EmC2014 UrbPop2014 `%UrbPop2014`   pop2014
   <chr>  <chr>             <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>         <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 EAP    Australia         AUS       1     263705.   15.5    15.4    20947819         0.893  23460694
 2 EAP    Brunei Darussalam BRN       2.09    6194.   23.9    22.1      316547         0.769    411704
 3 EAP    French Polynesia  PYF      NA        436.    2.20    2.92     154205         0.560    275484
 4 EAP    Japan             JPN       0.82 1096180.    8.87    9.54  118393408         0.930 127276000
 5 EAP    Korea, Rep.       KOR       0.74  246943.    5.76   11.6    41794948         0.824  50746659
 6 EAP    Malaysia          MYS       5.93   56593.    3.14    8.03   22371755         0.740  30228017
 7 EAP    Mongolia          MNG       1.89    9989.    4.57    7.13    2082457         0.712   2923896
 8 EAP    New Caledonia     NCL      NA       1584.    9.27   16.0      186697         0.697    268000
 9 EAP    New Zealand       NZL       1.1    23546.    7.07    7.69    3889661         0.863   4509700
10 EAP    Palau             PLW       1.73     235.   15.6    12.3       18236         0.865     21094
# ... with 70 more rows
```

Comment: I'm confused as to why you would do `group_by(rdatacities$region, rdatacities$country)` rather than the usual `group_by(region, country)`? Is there a reason you thought the data frame name was necessary? Also, you do understand that the code you reference uses that `group_by` as _additional_ code, as in your actual code wouldn't _begin_ with the group_by, it would _continue_ with it.

Comment: @joran when I remove the data frame name, I get this error: Error in group_by(region, country) : object 'region' not found

Comment: @joran I'm not quite sure where to place it in my code, I tried it just after geom_point() and inside theme(). I don't get any errors based on that, but it seems to have no effect on the plot. Am I putting it in the wrong place?

Comment: Are you using: rdatacities %>% group_by(region, country) ?

Comment: @SCDCE thanks for the suggestion.  I amended my code per your recommendation to: rdatacities %>% group_by(region,country) %>% 
but then it returned this error: Error in arrange_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: object 'contribution' not found. (I inserted that text after geom_point().  Is that the right place?

Comment: No, you're wanting to manipulate your data not the plot so it would come before you call ggplot().

Comment: @SCDCE thanks, I've moved it outside the plot. I also noticed that "contribution" (from: arrange(desc(contribution)) %>%) was a holdover from a copy/paste, so I changed it to one of my column headers: "country" though I don't know if this is correct.

This had no effect (the plot is still in the same incorrect order) and returned this warning: Warning message:
In `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  :
  duplicated levels in factors are deprecated